# how to extract and plot density using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a random vector, and trying to make density plot of it using ggplot
here is the vector

```
fridayKlient1<-c(134 ,135, 133, 137, 136)
```

then i used density over it

```
res<-density(data)
```

then i try to convert the result of `density` to data.frame to prepare for ploting:

```
  framer<-function(data){return  (data.frame(y=data$y, x=data$x)) }
```

and then plot it

```
res<-framer(density(fridayKlient1)) 
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x,y=y), colour="red" , data=res)
```

.
    but it complains with:

```
ggplot2: object 'y' not found
```

Comment: The returned object is a list with several components in addition to the x and y values of the density estimate (run `str(res)` to see what else is in the list). I think you just need `res1 = data.frame(res$x, res$y)`.

Comment: Or if you really just want to plot it,  `plot(density(data))`

Comment: @G5W no i want to overlay some layers so i need to use `ggplot() + geom_density`

Comment: OK,  then the comment of @eipi should work for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See `str(res)` for all components.

```
> head(data.frame(x = res$x, y = res$y))
         x            y
1 130.0792 0.0009454737
2 130.0985 0.0010042050
3 130.1178 0.0010641591
4 130.1370 0.0011299425
5 130.1563 0.0011970552
6 130.1755 0.0012693376
```

But to plot the density object in ggplot2, you would do

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = fridayKlient1), aes(x = x)) +
  geom_density()
```

Comment: @Salman it would seem you have already answered your question correctly.

Comment: No. This code gives the density of the `x` in the density object, which is entirely different to the actual density.

Comment: @mzuba you're right, it should plot the raw values.

Answer (score 2):

In order to plot the density of a given series, use `geom_density`. In order to plot an already existing density object, use `geom_line`.

```
fridayKlient1 <- c(134 ,135, 133, 137, 136)

res <- density(fridayKlient1)

# plot the results of the density call
ggplot(data.frame(x = res$x, y = res$y)) + 
  aes(x = x, y = y) + geom_line()

# plot the density using ggplot density method
ggplot(data.frame(x = fridayKlient1)) + 
  aes(x = x) + geom_density() + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(130, 140))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ggplot(data = res, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_density( colour="red" )
```

This should solve your problem. See geom_density() in ggplot2 docs. Else, go [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/density-plot-with-ggplot/).

Comment: where is `y` then?

Comment: Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class density.